# Issues with "R.” in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

already performed clean project, rebuild project, analysed and inspected code but it does not resolve the issue. This started when making "Slash Screen" i check my XML files it looks good to me, but started to realize in every `.Java` class i created symbol `R.` was underlined with red try everything i can think of....

```
`package com.example.dom.myapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    sleep(4000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                finally
                {
                    Intent myactivity = new Intent("com.example.dom.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(myactivity);
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}`
```

**Here's my Splash layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/front"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
```

***Here's my LogCat***

```
04-27 18:27:49.869 12888-12888/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
04-27 18:27:49.869 12888-12888/? E/Zygote: v2
04-27 18:27:49.879 12888-12888/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-27 18:27:55.679 12888-12945/com.example.dom.myapp E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
```

**Here's my AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dom.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityOne"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityThree"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityFour"></activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: android:background="@+id/drawable/front"
must be **android:background="@drawable/front"**
remove this @+id/

Answer (score 0):

In splash layout do this
android:background="@+id/drawable/front" must be android:background="@drawable/front" remove this @+id/

looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/front"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```